# How to access the `$index` in a compiled template: {name: 'xyz', foreach: ArrayItens}?

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates, knockout-2.0, cassette

I use the [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/) tool to compile the following template:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input 
            data-bind="value: Tipo, attr: { name: 'Telefones[' + $index + '].Tipo' }" 
            class="span2"
            placeholder="Tipo" 
            type="text">
        <input 
            data-bind="value: Id" 
            type="hidden">
        <input 
            data-bind="value: Ordem"
            type="hidden">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input 
            data-bind="phone: Numero, value: Numero"
            class="span2" 
            placeholder="Número" 
            type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
        <button data-bind="click: deletePhone" rel="nofollow">
            <i class="icon-trash"></i>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In my View:

```
<tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'rowTelefone', foreach: Telefones }"></tbody>
```

#### Question

I know KnockoutJS supports the `$index`, but when the template is compiled `$index` no longer exists.

**How can I access the `$index` in compiled template?**

Comment: did you try `$index()`? $index is an observable (a function), so to read its value you need the parens()

Comment: my thoughts exactly, $index is a computed observable - if it doesn't help, you probably have to dig into the rendered code.